# non-apple headset on ipad

Tags: headphones

I tried using my non-apple headset on ipad and it worked. This same headset is what I used on my android phone, but when I plugged it on my phone it won't work anymore. There's no headset logo appearing on my screen. Does this have anything to do about plugging the headset to the ipad?

Answer (score 2):

No, not as such.

You might have damaged the headset or the plug on the Android phone inadvertently, but it is not because you have plugged the headset into an iPad.

Comment: I guess so. It's still working on the ipad just not on the android phone anymore. I plugged it on my windows laptop, the sound's just not the same anymore. I guess I'll just have to buy a new one. Thanks for the reply.